# Laravel + Vue + Vite + defineAsyncComponent - Works with npm dev, fails with npm build

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I've been playing around with the newest version of Laravel framework and Vite. What I'm aiming for is to make it possible to load new VueJs components added to the 'js/components' folder dynamically using something called 'defineAsyncComponent'.

When you start with Laravel, it actually gives you a basic example in the 'app.js' file about how to automatically register components. However, this example doesn't use the 'defineAsyncComponent' method:

```
Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
    app.component(path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, ''), definition.default);
});
```

In my previous projects, I've manually used 'defineAsyncComponent' which works fine whether you're running the development mode ('npm run dev') or creating a production build ('npm run build'):

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
const ExampleComponent = defineAsyncComponent( () => import('./components/ExampleComponent.vue') );app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
```

By building on top of the example given in 'app.js', I've managed to make Vue components register dynamically using 'defineAsyncComponent'. It's all smooth sailing when I'm working with 'npm run dev', but there's a hiccup when I try 'npm run build'. In this case, the Vue components don't get properly processed or compiled.

```
let index = 0;
Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
    index++
    let mn = path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    let var_name = mn+'_'+index
    let module_name = var_name.replace('_'+index,"")
    let final_name = var_name.replace('_'+index,"")
    const camelToDashed = module_name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `-${letter.toLowerCase()}`).slice(1);
    window.defineAsyncComponent = defineAsyncComponent
    window.app = app
    let toEval = `const ${final_name} = window.defineAsyncComponent( () => import('./components/${module_name}.vue'));window.app.component('${camelToDashed}', ${module_name})`
    console.log(toEval);
    const exe = Function(toEval); exe();
    console.log(camelToDashed + ' is ready to be used, as '+module_name+'.')
});
```

Here's a snippet from my 'vite.config.js' file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
   
   
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],




    build: {

        minify: true,
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        cssMinify: true,

        reportCompressedSize: true,
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: true,

        outDir: './public/build/',
        sourcemap: true, 
        emptyOutDir: true, 

        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
                chunkFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]'
            },
        },

    },



    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },



});
```

Despite these efforts, I'm still facing this issue and I believe there might be something specific that I'm overlooking. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying and rectifying any potential problems in my setup that might be causing this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: can you please mention laravel version and please share the error message?

Comment: Sorry, Laravel 10

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way also but is not making use of defineAsyncComponent

### app.js file content:

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({});

let index = 0;
const components = []
Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
    
    index++
    var module_name = path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    const camelToDashed = module_name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `-${letter.toLowerCase()}`).slice(1);
    components[index] = defineAsyncComponent( () => import('./components/'+camelToDashed+'.vue') )
    app.component(path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, ''), definition.default)

});

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: This way works with npm run dev and npm run build but I am not sure if it's making use of defineAsyncComponent 